# Printf to buffer - faster than console?

Tags: c, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I am debugging some interrupt service routines (ISR) and need to print out the contents of a few registers whenever I enter the ISR. The firmware is in C.

There is an interrupt raised every few milli-seconds and if I printf() to the console, it is too slow and I end up missing interrupts. What is the fastest way to print something - either to a buffer or file or console- and any tips to do that?

[Additional info: I need to do some other things in the ISR -such as interrupt mask and compare, reset interrupts, enable interrupts and finally print out some registers.]

Thanks

Comment: Whilst the bulk of the time in `printf` will be the console interaction, you're probably better off just storing the register values somewhere, and then doing the text formatting outside your ISR.

Comment: Speed isn't a concept defined by C.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be to store the relevant data somewhere in a cache, and then print it, when you have time for it. Printing to the console is definitely slow, and using printf is maybe also not a good idea, especially if there are several variables to convert.

Since I don't know the dynamics of your code, I can only give some recommendation.

Define a datastructure for your data. Preallocate a big enough array, and then put ringbuffer mechanism, that handles the indexes of where the ISR can currently write. For the ISR this should be rather fast, because it just fills outr the values in the next empty slot.

In the main routine you can then print at leisure. However, you have to synchronize the access and also take care that the ISR doesn't produce data much faster than you can discard it. At least with a proper ringbuffer, it shouldn't crash, but you might loose information.

Comment: The problem is that I am currently trying to debug this. So I am just pumping thousands of external messages per second which raise interrupts. 

Can you suggest any method? When you mean cache, do you mean identify some memory location and write to it?

Also, to note: I am printing over a uart console at about 115k baud. So that is definitely very slow.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Either allocate a datastructure which is certainly faster, or if possible use a static array. Well, if you have thousands of logging entries, a statically sized buffer might not be an option though. Or you could preallocate a static sized array, that could work.

Comment: Thanks Devolus. I just resorted to doing this by creating a data structure. I am just concerned that the there is enough RAM to hold the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch buffering on by using C89's `setvbuf()`